# Why am I getting different scores on training data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search

I am trying to build an optimized SVM classification model using scikit-learn and I am fairly new in Python, not really in ML in general. Here's the code I am using:

```
# Training the SVM model on the Training set
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC()

# define evaluation
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=5, random_state=1)
# define search space
space = dict()
space['kernel'] = ["linear", "rbf", "sigmoid", "poly"]
space['C'] = [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
space['gamma'] = [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]
space['tol'] = [1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6]

# define search
search = RandomizedSearchCV(classifier, space, n_iter=500, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, random_state=1)

# execute search
result = search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# summarize result
print('Best Score: %s' % result.best_score_)
print('Best Hyperparameters: %s' % result.best_params_)
bestModel = result.best_estimator_

#Test
a = X_train
b = y_train
grid_predictions = bestModel.predict(a)
accuracy_score(b, grid_predictions)
```

I am trying to get how well my training data is classified. My question is: Why I am getting different accuracy outputs from `result.best_score_` (which is the best search model's accuracy) and `accuracy_score(b, grid_predictions)` (which is where the exact training data is fed to the model with best performance)?

Comment: I think `best_estimator_` is an estimator, not a value that you can compare with accuracy. Are you sure that this is what you're referring to? I think you want `best_score_`

Comment: @aaossa Yes, you are correct. I am correcting it. Thanks!

Comment: As the answer below explains, you are comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is because `best_score_` shows the best score (in your case, accuracy) of the best estimator, "estimator which gave highest score (or smallest loss if specified) on the left out data". The left out data comes from your cross validation, meaning that **is the accuracy on an unseen fold of your CV** (remember that this happens inside a [`RandomizedSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)).

On the other hand, the output of `accuracy_score(b, grid_predictions)` is calculated by the same predictor but over unseen data: not a fold, but **using all of your training data** (based on the code you provided).

This means that both metrics are calculated in the same manner, using the same model, but predicting on different sets of data.

Comment: Thanks very much! I am more familiar with h2o and just assumed best_score_ would return the accuracy of whole training data, not the fold. Thanks again.